# How can we execute custom method while Cascade="Delete" is being executed?

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, cascade

For example, I have two entities, "RealEstate" and "Picture". RealEstate holds a collection of Picture. In the mapping file RealEstate has a bag in it for Pictures and cascade is Delete".

If you delete a RealEstate all the related Pictures will be deleted. But is there any way to execute a custom method to delete the pictures from the web server.

I did it by assigning `cascade="none"` and when I delete a RealEstate i first check is there any Pictures related to it, if there is, I call `DeletePicture()` method for it.

I am curious about what do you do in these kind of situations?

Answer (score 2):

You could write an [interceptor](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-interceptors) and implement the **OnDelete** method that will be executed when a picture is deleted.

Comment: Thank you i will check it as soon as possible and mark it as answer,
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you're using nhibernate 2.0 , the new and better way to go is : use events.

Article about [nhibernate 2.0 events](http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/04/nhibernate-20-events-and-listeners.html)